# Will installing Ubuntu in Legacy Mode ruin Windows?

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, uefi, grub-legacy

I have a HP Pavilion Notebook with Windows 10, with the following specifications:

RAM : 8gb
Processor: Intel i5
HDD: 1TB
Graphic Card : 2gb ATI Raedon

And here is the `msinfo32` output:

```
OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Version 10.0.10240 Build 10240
Other OS Description    Not Available
OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation
System Name ABH
System Manufacturer Hewlett-Packard
System Model    HP Pavilion 15 Notebook PC
System Type x64-based PC
System SKU  E4Y17PA#ACJ
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3230M CPU @ 2.60GHz, 2601 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date   Insyde F.06, 5/28/2013
SMBIOS Version  2.7
Embedded Controller Version 95.25
BIOS Mode   Legacy
BaseBoard Manufacturer  Hewlett-Packard
BaseBoard Model Not Available
BaseBoard Name  Base Board
Platform Role   Mobile
Secure Boot State   Unsupported
PCR7 Configuration  Binding Not Possible
Windows Directory   C:\WINDOWS
System Directory    C:\WINDOWS\system32
Boot Device \Device\HarddiskVolume1
Locale  United States
Hardware Abstraction Layer  Version = "10.0.10240.16392"
User Name   Abh\Abhishek
Time Zone   India Standard Time
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 8.00 GB
Total Physical Memory   7.90 GB
Available Physical Memory   5.26 GB
Total Virtual Memory    9.15 GB
Available Virtual Memory    6.21 GB
Page File Space 1.25 GB
Page File   C:\pagefile.sys
Hyper-V - VM Monitor Mode Extensions    Yes
Hyper-V - Second Level Address Translation Extensions   Yes
Hyper-V - Virtualization Enabled in Firmware    Yes
Hyper-V - Data Execution Protection Yes
```

How do I proceed installing Windows on this Laptop? The bios mode clearly says `Legacy`, and all the guides I have seen say it shouldbe UEFI. Should I install it or not? And if not, then how can I change the Bios mode so that installing Ubuntu doesnt ruin my Windows Installation and lets me dual boot.

Answer (score 1):

Linux and Windows can run in legacy mode. They both can ALSO run in EFI mode.

It does not matter what you use, dual booting will not be an issue. However you will have issues if you attempt to install one as EFI and another as legacy. They cannot mix. It's all or nothing.

Install Windows first and then Ubuntu second. There are numerous guides that explain how to do this.

Comment: Okay. So, can you link some of the guides that work and will not brick my laptop?

Comment: There *are* ways to mix BIOS-mode and EFI-mode installations; however, it's almost always easier and safer to install them both in the same mode. As to doing it safely, there are about a bazillions guides on the Internet to doing a dual-boot. There are risks -- no method is 100% safe -- but the risks are manageable. Back up your data (especially your personal files) before beginning so that you can restore them in the event of a disaster.